# Python: Long data to wide data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have data like this

```
userid      day        x         y

user1       monday     1         2

user1       tuesday    3         4

user2       monday     10        11

user2       tuesday    12        13
```

I want to convert it to

```
userid      monday_x        monday_y      tuesday_x     tuesday_y

user1       1                  2             3              4

user2       10                 11            12             13
```

I tried using 'pivot' function. But I am not able to create new attributes names.
Then I tried manually copying each row. However, pandas is creating in the following way.

```
userid      monday_x        monday_y      tuesday_x     tuesday_y

user1       1                  2             NaN              NaN

user1       NaN              NaN             3                4

user2       10                 11            NaN              NaN

user2       NaN              NaN             12               13
```

Is there a built in function to do this kind of transformation in python?

Comment: What have you tried? Show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pivot_table` will work here.

```
df = df.pivot_table(
             index='userid', columns='day', values=['x', 'y'])\
       .sort_index(axis=1, level=-1)\
       .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)

df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

        monday_x  monday_y  tuesday_x  tuesday_y
userid                                          
user1          1         2          3          4
user2         10        11         12         13
```

Reset the index if need be. Use `df = df.reset_index()` to get `userid` as a column.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have also done this using pivot_table but for each and individual column and then combined all of them to get one table.
Thanks anyway.